# Allowing separate correct answers, Quiz

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a quiz game using javascript.

A quiz answer is stored in a variable like so:

```
var correctAnswer = $('#createCorrectAnswer').val();
```

And then I check if the answer is correct when a user answers:

```
if(answer == correctAnswer){
//Do something
}
```

How would I go about allowing questions where there can be more than one correct answer?

Comment: Two ways: One is checkboxes. Other is separate by commas. If you dont want to use checkboxes containing answers, so that user can select more than two. Then you could allow user to enter answers, separated by commas. In code, you could do a string-split and then validate if atleast one of them is the right anwer. Hope this helps. (You could upvote this, if it helps :) )

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity This sounds like what I am looking for! Change it to a answer and I will check it for correct answer =)

Comment: done. Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

- One is checkboxes.
- Other is separate by commas.

In checkbox option, user can select more than two. 
Other way is you could allow user to enter answers, separated by commas. In code, you could do a string-split and then validate if atleast one of them is the right anwer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use checkboxes but the string-split sounds like a dream solution. Thank you sir!

Comment: Hope it helped. You could accept this answer or probably, someone will provide a better answer than this, I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. create separate id for each question, or
2. dont use id, use class for answer, and use jquery selectors to find answer for each question (for example with closest, next, children etc)

Comment: I think you missunderstood. I am not looking for a way to check if 1 question has the right answer, I already did that. I am looking for a way to check if the user supplied several answers to check if atleast one is correct.